# Cannot convert from 'Dapper.CommandDefinition?' to 'string'

Tags: c#, async-await, dapper

I am currently using Dapper version 2.0.123 in my C# project and encountered an issue with the following code:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> QueryAsync<T>(CommandDefinition? command, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
    => (await ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.QueryAsync<T>(command))).AsList();

private async Task<T> ExecuteWithResiliency<T>(Func<string, object, SqlConnection, Task<T>> connectionFunc, string sql, object param = null, [CallerMemberName] string operation = "")
{
    return await _resiliencyPolicy.ExecuteAsync(
        ctx => connectionFunc(sql, param, (SqlConnection)_connection),
        ContextHelper.NewContext((SqlConnection)_connection, _logger, sql, param, operation));
}
```

The issue arises when trying to pass the CommandDefinition? parameter to c.QueryAsync(command) in the QueryAsync method. The error message states: "Cannot convert from 'Dapper.CommandDefinition?' to 'string'."

Upon further investigation, I found that in the Dapper namespace, the QueryAsync method is defined as follows:

```
public static Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(this IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command) =>
    QueryAsync<T>(cnn, typeof(T), command);
```

I'm seeking insights and suggestions on how to properly handle this situation and resolve the conversion error between CommandDefinition? and string in Dapper version 2.0.123. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Comment: I think the issue could be solved by passing the value/declaring the `command` variable as `CommandDefinition` type instead of `CommadDefinition?` which is nullable.

Comment: Try `ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.QueryAsync<T>(command.Value)))` or declare `QueryAsync` as `QueryAsync<T>(CommandDefinition command, ...`. But ideally post a full [mre] (for example on github).

Comment: Thanks @YongShun for your response. It helped me to fix the issue :)